# How to restore default menu in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: menu

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and hence this trivial query.

Situation 1:
Point 1: When I login as admin user the menu bar appears as shown below. 
Point 2: The active search bar is visible
Point 3: I can also start this menu by using default "Ctrl" + "Esc" key combination.

Admin User Menu display:

[image: Admin User Menu display]

Situation 2:
Point 1: The top left menu (start menu) looks different and wouldn't pop out when we press Ctrl + Esc keys.
Point 2: Also the active search component no longer is visible

Guest User Menu display:

[image: Guest User Menu display]

My question: Can you please help how I can get same menu as an admin user and also activate the menu with the Ctrl + Esc key combination rather than using mouse?

Thanks in advance,
Bhaskar

Comment: The menu in picture 1 is the whisker menu, as used by Xubuntu.  Are you sure you are running Ubuntu 18.04 and not Xubuntu.  Likewise picture 2 shows what looks to me like a XFCE menu (again used by Xubuntu, and not Ubuntu which uses the GNOME desktop not XFCE).   If you are using Xubuntu - you can use whichever menu you want (my Xubuntu system has both used)

Comment: You will find some help in the [ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession), it looks like copying some files and folders from a normal user account's home-directory to `/etc/guest-session/skel` would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find you are using Xubuntu 18.04 LTS and not Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  (though it's also possibly have started with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and added `xubuntu-desktop` or XFCE to your system)

On the panel you can add additional items.

Your picture 1 shows the Whisker Menu.
Your picture 2 shows the Applications Menu (traditional XFCE menu)

You can use/add either one in your panel (right click on empty space on the panel, select panel preferences, go to Items tab and click "+" to add additional items. Once added you can move them to where you want, or use "-" to remove unwanted items.  You can use either one, even both (I do, but I have multiple panels spread across my displays).

I suspect you'll find you are using Xubuntu 18.04 LTS though.

---

OP (@Bhaskar) provided the following

> ```
> > --> Add New Items
> > Step 2: Search for Whisker Menu
> > --> Select the Item
> > --> Click on Add Step
> > 3: Whisker Menu came up in the top right corner
> > Step 4: Right click on top panel
> > --> Remove
> > --> Application Menu Step
> > 5: Right click on Whisker Menu
> > --> Move (Dragged the menu from right to left corner).
> > Now the menu is fully accessible through key strokes.
> > Thank you for the solution.
> ```

Comment: I don't think that changes made in a guest account are persistent.

Comment: Hello,

My system configuration is as shown below (This is the terminal output from admin user).
bhaskar@LT-SRISAI:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
bhaskar@LT-SRISAI:~$

Comment: I think your suggestion solved my issue. Summary of the steps that I executed are:
Step 1: Right click on top panel --> Add New Items
Step 2: Search for Whisker Menu --> Select the Item --> Click on Add
Step 3: Whisker Menu came up in the top right corner
Step 4: Right click on top panel --> Remove --> Application Menu
Step 5: Right click on Whisker Menu --> Move (Dragged the menu from right to left corner).

Now the menu is fully accessible through key strokes.

Thank you for the solution.