# Admin --> GNome form of login, Guest --> Xubuntu form of login

Tags: login

Please find included the screenshot below that is common for the login window (Guest or Admin user)

[image: Guest or Admin User Login screen]

When I try to login into the Admin or Guest users as Gnome or other types of UI I still see that only XUbuntu session form of login is working. How to make other UIs work?

If I select anything other than XUbuntu then I return back to the login page always.

Please help me with the apt commands that I need to run so as to get Gnome and Mac OSX look and feel for both admin and guest users.

Thanks in advance,
Bhaskar

Comment: You haven't said what release you are using, however if you add gnome extensions that are not for the release of gnome you are using, gnome can crash & the user is logged out instantly (thus you can get login loop as you describe). Each release of Ubuntu using GNOME runs a specific release of gnome, so extensions must match the release of GNOME/Ubuntu or be compatible with that version (eg. Ubuntu 19.04 ships with GNOME 3.32)

Comment: I think that's not possible in 18.04, take a look at [this](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/guest-sessions-in-18-04-lts-are-they-needed/1714)

Comment: @guiverc https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164738/how-to-restore-default-menu-in-ubuntu-18-04